# Windows Server 2008 R2 backup includes volume with MSSQL data

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, backup

I'm using wbadmin to schedule image backup every night on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard server.

Ever since installing MS-SQL 2008 Express R2, wbadmin wants to also backup the volume where the MS-SQL data files are located (L:).

I'm using -allCritical to make sure bare metal restore will work.

command-line:

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:\\myserver\backup$\myserver\%DATE% -include:C: -allCritical -quiet
```

I don't want to do this, because I'm backing up MS-SQL manually elsewhere. It worked just fine only taking C: before I installed MS-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to tell the backup that the SQL files can't be backed up as trying to restore from the files that it backs up can't be used to restore.

Instead of running wbadmin start backup use wbadmin enable backup to schedule the backup. This gives you the option of using the -exclude parameter (you can try using this with start backup but I don't think it'll work).

Comment: Scheduling is not an option, because it only keeps one backup at a time. I need at least 3 days' worth of backups. Indeed, -exclude does not work with "start backup". Anyway, I worked around the issue by going back to SQL Server 2008 Express, not R2.